# Executable in a non-ROS workspace links to an executable in a ROS workspace

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, linker, ros, robotics

I'm working in ubuntu 20.04 and have ROS noetic. I have a catkin workspace (catkin_ws), and it has DBow2 in it at `/home/glenn/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libDBoW2.so`. I also have the library [ORB-SLAM3](https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3) installed on my system. It uses DBoW2 and has it installed in its `Thirdparty` folder, so after building this package, its location is at `/home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Thirdparty/DBoW2/lib/libDBoW2.so`.

When I try to run any executable from ORB-SLAM3, for example, `./Monocular/mono_euroc ../Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt ./Monocular/EuRoC.yaml ~/Documents/Trial_Data/euroc/V1_01 ./Monocular/EuRoC_TimeStamps/V101.txt dataset-V101_mono`, it gives the following error:

`./Monocular/mono_euroc: symbol lookup error: /home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/lib/libORB_SLAM3.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5DBoW24FORB1LE`

When I typed `ldd -r /home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/lib/libORB_SLAM3.so`, I get a large output, but the relevant one to my issue is the following line:

`libDBoW2.so => /home/glenn/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libDBoW2.so (0x00007fd840758000)`

which shows it's pointing to the DBoW library from the catkin workspace and not the ORB_SLAM3 workspace. To get around this, I simply comment out `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` line in my bashrc and source it again, the same line from the same command gets the right output:

`libDBoW2.so => /home/glenn/ORB_SLAM3/Thirdparty/DBoW2/lib/libDBoW2.so (0x00007f9136949000)`

and everything in ORB_SLAM3 works fine again.

I just wanted to know if there was a better way to manage a shared library looking in the wrong place at runtime without having to constantly comment out the line to source my catkin workspace? From ORB_SLAM3's CMakeLists.txt [lines 118-126](https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L118-L126), it seems they do link to the appropriate DBoW library under the Thirdparty folder. I was thinking of possibly setting the RPATH by adding the following lines to the top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
```

but that gave significantly more errors for libORB_SLAM3.so. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.